# Magento API to create same categoy on another magento

Tags: magento-1.8, api, category

how to add category automatically in another magento {A} while adding category manually in magento {B}.

Suppose i am adding category manually in magento {B} than it will automatically insert/create category in another magento {A} automatically.can it possible if yes please let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to either implement an observer which rans on catalog_category_save_after and checks for new ID or a cron job which checks somewhow for new categories.

Then just login to the api of the other magento and call `category.create`
 http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.create.html